# How to disable ReSharper ConvertToAutoProperty warning for specific properties?

Tags: c#, resharper

I would like to do something like:

```
public class TaskDto : IDto
{
    //ReSharper disable ConvertToAutoProperty
    private int _id;
    public int ID { get { return _id; }}
    //ReSharper enable ConvertToAutoProperty
}
```

ConvertToAutoProperty isn't the correct name of the rule -- I was just taking a stab at it. Google isn't turning up anything. I don't see the ability to suppress the warning via the ReSharper context menu. I still would like to see this rule in general, just not for IDs in my DTO classes.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Wherever you see an auto-fix balloon (the light bulb) you should be able to click the light bulb and change how or if R# shows you that particular issue.

Comment: I am hoping to address this with code. We don't keep our configuration files synced between developers (yet), but I would like other developers to not convert to an auto-property as our program will break if this occurs.

Comment: Does the light bulb not give you the option to disable with a comment?

Comment: As stated in the original question -- "I do not see the ability to suppress the warning via the R# context menu." I have uploaded a screenshot which displays the context menu options I am presented with.

Comment: I see your image, there must be some options that can't be disabled via comments I guess.

Comment: Yeah :( Frustrating! I'll continue to Google, maybe something will come up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: JetBrains has a forum as well.  I would suggest asking this question on that forum.  I would be curious to know the answer though since I have also run into this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
// ReSharper disable ConvertToAutoPropertyWithPrivateSetter
private int _id;
public int ID { get { return _id; } }
// ReSharper restore ConvertToAutoPropertyWithPrivateSetter
```

ReSharper should have offered you an option to generate this automatically. Seems like a bug here, so created a request here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-329913

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I see you created the bug -- awesome!